# How to properly import a semicolon-separated file

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread, read.csv

I have been trying to import the following semi-colon separated file:

```
# word  len;freq;mean;sens;npos;u;orthon;freqn;bgp  WN000000
fiber   "5;8.671;1;5;1;0;5;6.1;0;-1"    10000000
clad    "4;6.78;2;2;1;1;8;7.84;2026;-1" 10000000
tucker  "6;8.103;2;3;2;0.91829583405449;7;5.5;4547;-1"  10000000
```

I tried both `read.csv` and `data.table::fread`, but with no luck. `read.csv` recognizes some of headers and the actual values are all under the first column:

```
 X..word.len freq mean sens npos  u orthon freqn bgp.WN000000
1 fiber\t5;8.671;1;5;1;0;5;6.1;0;-1\t10000000   NA   NA   NA   NA NA     NA    NA           NA
2 clad\t4;6.78;2;2;1;1;8;7.84;2026;-1\t10000000   NA   NA   NA   NA NA     NA    NA           NA
3 tucker\t6;8.103;2;3;2;0.91829583405449;7;5.5;4547;-1\t10000000   NA   NA   NA   NA NA     NA    NA           NA
```

`fread` recognizes the first column, but merges all the others into one.

```
  X..word    len.freq.mean.sens.npos.u.orthon.freqn.bgp WN000000
1   fiber                    5;8.671;1;5;1;0;5;6.1;0;-1 10000000
2    clad                 4;6.78;2;2;1;1;8;7.84;2026;-1 10000000
3  tucker  6;8.103;2;3;2;0.91829583405449;7;5.5;4547;-1 10000000
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: None of this is copy/pastable into R. Please show your raw text file.

Comment: Did you use `sep=";"` with `read.csv` ?

Comment: @G5W: I did. The problem with that command, is that the actual values are put in the first column, and not properly distributed in the headers.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I try (and edited based on  David Arenburg 's comment).

Read and process the header line first; then read the remaining lines while skipping the first line:

```
library(data.table)

header <- strsplit(readLines('test.txt', n = 1), '\\s+')[[1]][-1]
res <- fread('test.txt', skip = 1, header = FALSE)
setnames(res, 1:3, header)

res[, strsplit(header[2], ';')[[1]] :=
        tstrsplit(get(header[2]), ';', type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)[-10]]

res[, header[2] := NULL]

#      word WN000000 len  freq mean sens npos         u orthon freqn  bgp
# 1:  fiber 10000000   5 8.671    1    5    1 0.0000000      5  6.10    0
# 2:   clad 10000000   4 6.780    2    2    1 1.0000000      8  7.84 2026
# 3: tucker 10000000   6 8.103    2    3    2 0.9182958      7  5.50 4547
```

It should be noted that there are 9 items seperated by `;` in second column of the input file, but the following rows have 10 `;`-seperated items.

Comment: this works great, many many thanks. One question - what does := do?

Comment: @RobertP. It is an operator used to do "assignment by reference" for a `data.table`. You can find more info here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you've basically got two separators working there. It might be worth handling this manually, rather than using a standard reading function.

Read the file in, get rid of the quotations, then separate by both space and semicolon delimiters.

```
library( magrittr )
input <- readLines( "~/Desktop/Untitled" ) %>%
    gsub( '"|^# +', "", . ) %>%
    strsplit( "\\ +|;" )
```

Convert everything except the first row to a data frame.

```
input[-1] %>%
    do.call( what = rbind ) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

Then use the first row as column names. We need to add an extra here, since your header doesn't have enough names to cover your data.

```
names( df ) <- c( input[[1]][1:10], "fill.col", input[[1]][11] )
```

Result:

```
> df
    word len  freq mean sens npos                u orthon freqn  bgp fill.col WN000000
1  fiber   5 8.671    1    5    1                0      5   6.1    0       -1 10000000
2   clad   4  6.78    2    2    1                1      8  7.84 2026       -1 10000000
3 tucker   6 8.103    2    3    2 0.91829583405449      7   5.5 4547       -1 10000000
```

Comment: this looks a nice solution, although it gives an incorrect result - the first column should be "len", not word. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As @mt1022 noticed, your header doesn't match your data. I let the first column name be a hash, since that's what was in your header. If you want to shift the names, but still make sure you keep all your data, you need to add an extra column name. I've updated to do just that.